# How to select last order on SF Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a database consisting of over 1 million orders, I'm looking to select the last order (indicated by OrderDate) for a customer (indicated as CustomerID).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ORDERDATE) AS ORDERDATE,
    ORDERID,
    ORDERITEMID,
    ITEMID,
    MENUITEMNAME,
    ITEMSIZE,
    CUSTOMERID,
    ORDERDATETIME,
    APPNAME,
    UNITID,
    UNIT_NAME,
    UNIT_DETAIL_NAME,
    SECTOR,
    STOREID,
    STORENAME,
    ADDRESS_COUNTRY,
    TRANSACTIONTYPEREFID,
    BRANDNAME,
    PAYMENTTYPE,
    VOLANTETRANSACTIONID,
    PROMOTIONCODE,
    DISCOUNTAMOUNT,
    DISCOUNT_VALUEISAMOUNT,
    QUANTITY,
    SALES,
    PRICECURRENCYCODE,
    LIVE,
    TIMEZONE,
    LOAD_DATE 
FROM CDL_DH_DATAMART
GROUP BY  
    ORDERID,
    ORDERITEMID,
    ITEMID,
    MENUITEMNAME,
    ITEMSIZE,
    CUSTOMERID,
    ORDERDATETIME,
    APPNAME,
    UNITID,
    UNIT_NAME,
    UNIT_DETAIL_NAME,
    SECTOR,
    STOREID,
    STORENAME,
    ADDRESS_COUNTRY,
    TRANSACTIONTYPEREFID,
    BRANDNAME,
    PAYMENTTYPE,
    VOLANTETRANSACTIONID,
    PROMOTIONCODE,
    DISCOUNTAMOUNT,
    DISCOUNT_VALUEISAMOUNT,
    QUANTITY,
    SALES,
    PRICECURRENCYCODE,
    LIVE,
    TIMEZONE,
    LOAD_DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

You want to partition and sort your result to get the first record.

```
SELECT 

    ORDERDATE, 
    ORDERID, 
    ORDERITEMID, 
    ITEMID,
    MENUITEMNAME, 
    ITEMSIZE, 
    CUSTOMERID, 
    ORDERDATETIME, 
    APPNAME, 
    UNITID, 
    UNIT_NAME, 
    UNIT_DETAIL_NAME,
    SECTOR, 
    STOREID, 
    STORENAME, 
    ADDRESS_COUNTRY,
    TRANSACTIONTYPEREFID,
    BRANDNAME, 
    PAYMENTTYPE, 
    VOLANTETRANSACTIONID,
    PROMOTIONCODE, 
    DISCOUNTAMOUNT,
    DISCOUNT_VALUEISAMOUNT, 
    QUANTITY, 
    SALES, 
    PRICECURRENCYCODE, 
    LIVE, 
    TIMEZONE, 
    LOAD_DATE 

From (

    Select
        ORDERDATE, 
        ORDERID, 
        ORDERITEMID, 
        ITEMID,
        MENUITEMNAME, 
        ITEMSIZE, 
        CUSTOMERID, 
        ORDERDATETIME, 
        APPNAME, 
        UNITID, 
        UNIT_NAME, 
        UNIT_DETAIL_NAME,
        SECTOR, 
        STOREID, 
        STORENAME, 
        ADDRESS_COUNTRY,
        TRANSACTIONTYPEREFID,
        BRANDNAME, 
        PAYMENTTYPE, 
        VOLANTETRANSACTIONID,
        PROMOTIONCODE, 
        DISCOUNTAMOUNT,
        DISCOUNT_VALUEISAMOUNT, 
        QUANTITY, 
        SALES, 
        PRICECURRENCYCODE, 
        LIVE, 
        TIMEZONE, 
        LOAD_DATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMERID ORDER BY ORDERDATE DESC) as ID_Row 
    FROM CDL_DH_DATAMART 

) as A 
WHERE ID_Row = 1
```